# Pyinstaller wont import a pkg into the exe file / failed to execute the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to create an executable program with **pyinstaller**, but after creating the file successfully, and when I want to run the file, I have the error, this is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun May 24 18:18:00 2020

@author: MeTaNa
"""

'''
this program is simple, notifys u if battery is fully charged,
'''

import psutil
from time import sleep
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()

while True:
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    plugged = battery.power_plugged
    percent = str(battery.percent)
    if plugged==False: plugged="Not Plugged In"
    else: plugged="Plugged In"
    if (psutil.sensors_battery().power_plugged == True) and (battery.percent == 100):
        print(percent+'% | '+plugged)
        print('Unplug the Charger Please!')
        toaster.show_toast('Battery Statues','Battery Full.\nUnplug the Charger Please!')
        sleep(600)
    elif (psutil.sensors_battery().power_plugged == False)and (battery.percent != 100):
        print(percent+'% | '+plugged)
        print('Thank Your.')
        toaster.show_toast('Battery Statues','Charger Not Plugged')
        sleep(3600)
    else:
        print(percent+'% | '+plugged)
        print('Thank Your.')
        toaster.show_toast('Battery Statues','Charging...')
        sleep(3600)
```

the error is:[image]

and program doesnt run, it says: `Fatal Error: program failed to execute script,`

as I understood, pyinstaller didn't import the `win10toast` to the .exe file, and I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: i also tried the `auto-py-to-exe` same resault, something is wrong with `win10toast? or am i doing something wrong? i really dont get it,

Answer (score 1):

ok, i found a strange way to solve!
just edited this lines:
`toaster.show_toast('Battery Statues','Battery Full.\nUnplug the Charger Please!',icon_path='')`
and all of the same lines, its running now, i think library has some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this QA
[PyInstaller file fails to execute script - DistributionNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076795/pyinstaller-file-fails-to-execute-script-distributionnotfound/52898981#52898981)

You need to create a new py file in

```
..\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

hook-win10toast.py
```

The content should be:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('win10toast')
```