# PyInstaller and Google Vision - errors while converting

Tags: python, python-import, pyinstaller, google-cloud-vision

I wrote simple Python script with GUI for scanning handwriting from photos, using Google Vision.
Idea is to import code into executable program, so my friend may use this program on his windows PC.

I am trying to import this code to .exe via auto-py-to-exe, but I keep getting errors, most of them are about django related imports.

Is it possible to convert this script into .exe at all?

There is my script code:

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import os
import io

execution_path = os.getcwd()
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=r'XXXXXXXXXXXX.json'

dest = ''

def OCR():
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    path = dest
    image_file = io.open(path,'rb').read()
    image1 = vision.types.Image(content = image_file)
    response = client.text_detection(image = image1)
    global doc_text
    doc_text = response.full_text_annotation.text
    print(doc_text)
 


from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.show()
        self.openb.clicked.connect(self.openFileNameDialog)
        self.readb.clicked.connect(self.reading)
            
        
    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        global dest
        dest = fileName
        print(dest)
        if fileName:
            #print(fileName)
            self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(fileName))
            
        
            
    def reading(self):
        OCR()
        self.result.setText(doc_text)
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

And here is pyinstaller output

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.7.6
Building directory: C:\Users\mukanrom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_9eu06ny
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console  "C:/label reader/label_reader.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console C:/label reader/label_reader.py --distpath C:\Users\mukanrom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_9eu06ny\application --workpath C:\Users\mukanrom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_9eu06ny\build --specpath C:\Users\mukanrom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_9eu06ny

93640 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
93644 INFO: Python: 3.7.7
93647 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
93651 INFO: wrote C:\Users\mukanrom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_9eu06ny\label_reader.spec
93657 INFO: UPX is not available.
93661 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\label reader', 'C:\\Users\\mukanrom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_9eu06ny']
93665 INFO: checking Analysis
93668 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
93672 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
93683 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
93695 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
95908 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
95913 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\documents\\wpy64-3770\\python-3.7.7.amd64\\lib'
97515 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
97607 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
97628 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\python.exe
97700 INFO: Analyzing C:\label reader\label_reader.py
108983 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
109942 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
109948 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\documents\\wpy64-3770\\python-3.7.7.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
124233 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
134498 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
136163 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v3
136278 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v2
136587 INFO: Processing module hooks...
136591 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
136596 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
136921 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
136926 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.cache.py"...
137107 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.mail.py"...
137158 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.management.py"...
137178 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'IPython'
137184 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
137192 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'matplotlib'
137195 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.py"...
138715 WARNING: Hidden import "django.db.backends.__pycache__.base" not found!
138718 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.py"...
140567 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
242008 INFO: Packages required by django:
['asgiref', 'sqlparse', 'pytz']
259593 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-docutils.py"...
262424 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
262547 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-gevent.py"...
262852 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.
262857 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.
262860 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
262869 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi', 'setuptools']
264109 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-google.api.py"...
264116 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-google.api_core.py"...
264121 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-google.cloud.py"...
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\mukanrom\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_9eu06ny\label_reader.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 422, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 311, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 417, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 384, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 797, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-google.cloud.py", line 13, in <module>
    datas = copy_metadata('google-cloud-core')
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 859, in copy_metadata
    dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution(package_name)
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 482, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 358, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "c:\documents\wpy64-3770\python-3.7.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076795/pyinstaller-file-fails-to-execute-script-distributionnotfound) out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyInstaller file fails to execute script - DistributionNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076795/pyinstaller-file-fails-to-execute-script-distributionnotfound)